# What is editor-style.css file in WordPress theme directory?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, cpanel

I have a WordPress site and I am using the Hestia theme. There is a file named editor-style.css in my theme directory. I don't know what exactly it is.
Can anyone tell me? Or a link to another website for more details?

Comment: google produced this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to edit the style of the back end, post editor page. Usually not required, but useful if creating a blog with many authors.

Comment: Can we consider that this is just for admins of the site?

Comment: Admins, Authors and Editor users who would see the Add New Posts page.